# react component class variable access

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How do I access this `the_frame` variable?

```
export default class oneApp extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        const the_frame = document.getElementsByClassName("frame")[0];
    }

    oneFunc() {  
        the_frame.style.display = "none"; // How do I access the_frame ?
    }

    twoFunc() {
        the_frame.style.display = "block"; 
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="frame">Hello World</div>
        )
    }
}
```

I also tried `this.the_frame = document.getElementsByClassName("frame")[0];` but can't access `the_frame`. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `ref` attribute if you would like a reference to the DOM element.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 2):

In react you need to use refs. React manages the rendering so you have no guarantee that your element i accessible the moment you are trying to reach it. It in the constructor so your render haven run yet.

More reading
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html